# How to highlight all duplicate rows except NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe like this

| Date | ID_1 | ID_2 | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-2-3 | 12 | 23 | Sam |
| 2021-2-3 | 12 | 56 | Sem |
| 2021-2-3 | 33 | 56 | Tom |
| 2021-2-3 | 35 | 45 | Jon |
| 2021-2-3 | 35 | 23 | Sam |
| 2021-2-3 | Nan | 99 | Jim |
| 2021-2-3 | 35 | Nan | Jon |
| 2021-2-3 | 88 | 44 | Sam |

I want to highlight all the duplicate rows green with just the same IDs

| Date | ID_1 | ID_2 | Name | Hightlight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-2-3 | 12 | 23 | Sam | True |
| 2021-2-3 | 12 | 56 | Sem | True |
| 2021-2-3 | 33 | 56 | Tom | True |
| 2021-2-3 | 35 | 45 | Jon | True |
| 2021-2-3 | 35 | 23 | Sam | True |
| 2021-2-3 | Nan | 99 | Jim |  |
| 2021-2-3 | 35 | Nan | Jon | True |
| 2021-2-3 | 88 | 44 | Sam |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.style` with a custom function:

```
def duplicated(s):
    if s.name.startswith('ID'):
        return (s.duplicated()&s.notna()).map({True: 'background-color:green', False: None})
    else:
        return [None]*len(s)

df.style.apply(duplicated, axis=0)
```

Or better:

```
def duplicated(s):
    return (s.duplicated()&s.notna()).map({True: 'background-color:green', False: None})
df.style.apply(duplicated, subset=df.columns.str.startswith('ID'), axis=0)
```

[image: highlight]

Edit: for fun, here is a way to highlight the initial duplicate with a different color:

```
def duplicated(s):
    return ((s.duplicated().astype(int)
            +s.duplicated(keep=False).astype(int)
            )*s.notna().astype(int)
            ).map({2: 'background-color:green;color:white',
                   1: 'background-color:lightgreen',
                   0: None})
df.style.apply(duplicated, subset=df.columns.str.startswith('ID'), axis=0)
```

[image: two color highlight]

Comment: Thank you it does highlight only the duplicate IDs but It also highlights the 'nan' values how do I ignore that?

Comment: Generally speaking it would be better practice to `subset` the `apply` instead of calculating a None column. `df.style.apply(duplicated, subset=df.columns.str.startswith('ID'), axis=0)` then you can get rid of the `if/else` in `duplicated` and just return the `s.duplicated()...map(...`